# How to write a syntax to login from one machine to another in Robotframework in automation

Tags: robotframework

I am in one machine from that I want to login to another virtual machine. That is possible only from the command "ssh -p 29030 root@10.43.38.242" and the password is also "root".

I want to automate this logging in RobotFramework but normal "Open Connection" function is not working.

Could anyone please help me out in this?

Comment: Are you using this SSH library https://github.com/robotframework/SSHLibrary ? What exactly have you tried so far? In what way it did not work?

Comment: Yes SSHLibrary using. I tried the following ways. 1.Directly used "Open Connection" function with second argument given as port-29030, didnot work. 2.used "Write" function of robotframework that also didnot work.

Comment: In what way it did not work? After Open connection, you need to use Login or Login with public key.

Comment: Ya Open Connection   10.43.38.242   29030 
   Login       root          root    but this is not logging into the machine. this i want to login to this VM from another machine.

Comment: Can you open SSH connection manually from one VM to another?

Comment: yes yes manually using "ssh -p 29030 root@10.43.38.242" I am able to login. I am trying to automate this but normal way using Open Connection function it is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Does it give an error? What does it write to the log?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that SSH Library is installed and SSH connection works from one VM to another whne opening it manually, here's the the test suite file

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SSHLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Login
    Open Connection    10.43.38.242    None    29030
    Login    root    root
```

Comment: ok. but second argument is for port right? can you tell me what is the significance of 'None' in second argument

Comment: From the documentation http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/latest/SSHLibrary.html#Open%20Connection second argument is 'alias'. "Optional alias can be given for the connection and can be used for switching between connections, similarly as the index. See Switch Connection for more details."

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try hope this suffice my requirement.

Comment: In what way it did not work? What is the exact test case you tried? What is the possible error message? How did the outcome differ from expected outcome?

Comment: It did not logged in. Error is                                        14:55:04.313  INFO  Logging into '10.43.38.242:29030' as 'root'.
14:55:25.323  FAIL  error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: And that's most probably due to network/firewall/... configuration. So check that your firewall etc. does not block SSH connection form the VM to another VM.